# Find the expectation of an exponential that includes an integral in the exponent

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_i)$ be an i.i.d sequence of random variables with marginal distribution $\mu$. Let $L_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \delta_{X_i}$ be the empirical measure and $f$ any bounded continuous function. I need to prove the equality $$\mathbb{E}[e^{n\int f dL_n}] = (\int e^f d\mu)^n.$$ I am confused with the change of measure and how the exponential gets exchanged with the integral. I am following the definition of the expectation but can not come to the result. Can you provide some help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $\int fd\delta_x=f(x)$.

$\int fd\delta_{X_i}=f(X_i)$  and $\int fdL_n=\frac 1 n [f(X_1)+f(X_2)+...+f(X_n)]$. Now use indepedence of $e^{f(X_i)}$ and the fact that  $Ee^{f(X_i)}=\int e^{f}d\mu$.

I am using a **very basic theorem** from Measure/Probability Theory:
If $X$ has distribution $\mu$ then $\int g(X)dP=\int g(x)d\mu(x)$ for any non-negative mesurable function $g$.

This proved by the standard procedure of verifying it for an indicator funciton, then taking linear combinations and then writing $g$ as an increasing limit of simple functions.

Comment: Thanks. How the marginal distribution  $\mu$ comes here into play?

Comment: $Ee^{f(X_i)}=\int e^{f} d\mu$ since $X_i \sim \mu$. @user996159

Comment: Why they call it marginal distribution and not simply the distribution? I do not see here the need for joint or marginal distribution. This was confusing me.

Comment: They are just saying that each $X_i$ has distribution $\mu$.  @user996159

Comment: Is there a typo in your answer, in which you say that $Ee^{f(X_i)} = e^{\int fd\mu},$ instead of $Ee^{f(X_i)} = \int e^f d\mu$ ?

Comment: @user996159 Yes, of course.

Comment: The key point here is $Ee^{f(X_i) } = \int e^fd\mu. $ Given that the r.v. we are looking the expectation after is $e^{f(X_i) } $ and not $X_i$, while at the other hand we are given the distribution of $X_i, $ I am wondering how this works together. With $Y(x) := e^{f(x)} $ and $Ee^{f(X_i)} = \int e^f dY,$ I do not know if one can use $dy = f'(x) e^{f(x)} dx$ and thus get $Ee^{f(X_i)} =\int e^f dY =\int e^f f'(x) e^f dx. $ This is different from $\int e^f d\mu, $ unless we set $d\mu=f' e^f dx. $ Can you explain how one goes from $\int e^f dY$ to $\int e^f d\mu$?

Comment: Let $g(x)=e^{f(x)}$. Then $Eg(X_i)=\int g(x) d\mu(x)$. So $Ee^{f(X_i)}=\int e^{f(x)} d\mu(x)$. @user996159

Comment: But $\mu$ is the distribution of  $X_i$ and not of $g(X_i). $ Do the two random variables $X_i, g(X_i), $ have the same distribution? The appropriate change of measure makes for me the things unclear.